# Detecting if another computer connects

Tags: windows

AS an administrator I can access other computers on the same LAN by using driver$ like

```
\\anothercomputer\c$
```

and find what I want in their computer. My question is that whether they can find out somebody has connected to their PC, In Event Viewer or when they want to shut down the computer or ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes (If Logon Events are Logged)

You can only access a share on a remote PC (e.g. via `\\REMOTEPC\SHARENAME`) if you can logon the remote PC with an account with sufficient privileges to do so.  Therefore, accessing a share triggers a logon to the remote PC. All logons to a PC are logged in the Security event log (assuming such event logging is enabled).

If logon events are logged, event ID **4624** will be logged in the Security Event Log (Windows Vista+).  It looks like this:

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

New Logon:
    Security ID:        DOMAIN\user
    Account Name:       user
    Account Domain:     DOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x3f33d66
    Logon GUID:     {6dad1ee6-55ea-50af-7561-0289b6364aad}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: 192.168.1.10
    Source Port:        55372

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Kerberos
    Authentication Package: Kerberos
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

The additional text in the event provides more explanation:

> This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is
>   generated on the computer that was accessed.
>
> The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which
>   requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the
>   Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or
>   Services.exe.
>
> The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The
>   most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).
>
> The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was
>   created, i.e. the account that was logged on.
>
> The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated.
>   Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some
>   cases.
>
> The authentication information fields provide detailed information
>   about this specific logon request.
>     - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
>     - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
>     - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
>     - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.

Comment: It's worth noting that non administrators cannot access the Security event log by default.